# How many different(but overlapping) master degree can one have?

Tags: masters

Take an example, if I have a master in mathematical physics, can I have master of physics or master in mathematics?

To make the the question more applicable to other, the question is, how many different master one could have, with the contents of the degree highly overlapping?

(Another example is master in information engineering and master of information science, etc)

Comment: But *why*? _____

Comment: The average American lives for 72ish years.  The average masters degree takes about 2 years to complete.  If you start earning masters degree at a rate of one ever two years, starting at age 22 (the typical age of completion for a bachelors degree, assuming that one completes high school at age 18 and takes 4 years on a bachelors degree), then one could earn about 25 masters degrees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no regulations preventing you from having as many as you like. But admissions committees will use the fact that you have a related degree and possibly downgrade the application so that the slot can be given to someone else. That isn't guaranteed, of course.

But at a certain point one wonders why you would want to do this. Lifelong perpetual students aren't looked at especially favorably. Especially when institutions are government funded to some extent.

And, if you want to continue your education, why not consider a doctorate in a related field instead. There is little benefit (some) if your CV shows multiple masters.

An exception might be if you were interested in industry and one of the masters program was very narrow and applied to the industry sector you want to work in.

Comment: Let me add that many master programms do (have to) admit everybody with a relvant bachelor degree without any committee.